# javascript If functions are objects then why doesn't this work

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = function () { this.bar = 1; }

>> foo.bar 
undefined
```

How do I access the property of a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:

```
var foo = function () { this.bar = 10; return this; } ();

console.log(foo.bar);
```

Read about self executing functions here:

[What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You syntax is wrong:

```
function foo() {  this.bar = 1; }
var a = new foo();
a.bar; // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a definition. You need to instantiate it.

```
var foo = function () { this.bar = 1; }

>> new foo().bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you've only defined `foo` and not actually executed it.  Hence the line `this.bar = 1` hasn't even run yet and there is no way for `bar` to be defined.

The next problem is that when you run `foo` it will need a context which `this` will be defined in.  For example

```
var x = {}
foo.apply(x);
x.bar === 1 // true
```

Or alternatively you could run `foo` as a constructor and access `bar` on the result

```
var x = new foo();
x.bar === 1 // true
```